# Using the Manipulate funvtion in Mathematica:

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How is it possible to extend the scope of the slider variable beyong the 'Manipulate' function?  In this coding 'n' = 10 before and after the 'Manipulate' function but can vary between -10 and +10 in the plot routine.

```
n = 10;
Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[n*x], {x, -5, 5}], {n, -10, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
   Print["n = ", n]
```

Thank you in advance for all contributors.
Norman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another variable name for the control variable in the Manipulate.

```
n = 10;
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[(n = m)*x], {x, -5, 5}], {{m, n}, -10, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
Print["n = ", Dynamic[n]]
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, Chris.  It works great but I don't understand how it works, namely having a '(n=m)' in the argument of a function!